# $0\notin B$ and for every $A\subseteq B$ it holds V=$span\left(A\right)\oplus span\left(B\backslash A\right)$ show that B is a basis of V.

Tags: linear-algebra

let V be a vector space and, $B\subseteq V$ , prove that if $0\notin B$  and for every $A\subseteq B$  it holds V=$span\left(A\right)\oplus span\left(B\backslash A\right)$ thn B is a basis of V.

to prove that span(B)=V is simple enough, we can define $A=B\subseteq B$ and that we get

V=$span\left(A\right)\oplus span\left(B\backslash A\right) = span(B)\oplus$ {$0$}$=span(B)$.

but i couldn't figure out how to prove that B is linear independent, i tried assuming that B is linear dependent but could get to a contradiction can someone help?

Comment: Hint: $B$ is linearly dependent if and only if there exists some $x \in B$ such that $x \in \operatorname{span}(B \setminus \{x\})$.

Comment: yeah i tried that, i represented $x$ as a linear combination of vectors from $B$\{$x$} but cant mange to see how to get to a contradiction

Comment: is this true? What if $V=\mathbb R^2$ and $B=\{(1,0), (0,1), (1,1)\}$?

Comment: oh wow look like you are correct the statement doesn't hold for this example

Comment: @JohnDouma there is an $A\subseteq B$, such that the precondition $span(A)\oplus span(B\setminus A) = V$ does not hold, because $span(A)\cap span(B\setminus A)\neq \{0\}$. So your counterexample does not work.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Zero is in the span of every subset. The span of the empty set is zero and for any collection of non-zero vectors $v_1,...v_n$ we get zero by multiplying each element by zero.

Comment: @JohnDouma take $A = \{(1,1)\}$ and $B = \{(0,1), (1,0)\}$, then is $span(A)\cap span(B) = \{0\}$?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Yes. I was considering the sum $A+B$, not the direct sum.

Comment: @LielAzulay There's your proof. If there is a redundant vector then it is in the span of itself and its complement so you can get linearly independence.

Comment: thank you everyone i managed to prove the statement

Comment: By assumptions $V={\rm span}\,\{b\}\oplus {\rm span}\,(B\setminus \{b\})$ Therefore   the sets $b$ and $B\setminus\{b\}$  are linearly independent.
Thus the set $B$  is a basis of $ {\rm span}\,(B).$